# Wait for the Process to finish and update JProgressBar in Java

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I am a newbie to Java programming. I have a program that executes a system command using Runtime exec `Process` and I want it while the `Process` is running, the `JProgressBar` indicator is updating. How can I do this programmatically?

My code is something like:

```
...
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command_goes_here);

    int error = p.waitFor();

    // Then the JProgressBar???

    System.out.println((error == 0 ? "Success" : "Failed"));
}
```

Comment: I found a duplicate which pretty much gives you the answer. I suspect that you were using the wrong terms for your Google search since searching on Swing JProgressBar process gives quick hits to many similar solutions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry for this late reply. I am currently trying to implement the answer to the "duplicate question". The answer uses the `ProcessBuilder` which is in my case is different so I'm having a hard time here, and I don't understand the other code used (cause there isn't any comment). I'm really sorry.

Comment: In fact you should be using a ProcessBuilder instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` to get your Process. Read the API on ProcessBuilder to see how to use it. Next, you should gain an understanding of Swing thread issues. Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) (yes, all of it) to gain this understanding.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My bad for asking such noobie question... I'll work on it. Thanks! Though I got the Runtime exec `Process` code working perfect in my program, I'll also try the `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Does `ProcessBuilder` requires an external file like **.BAT** **.SH**? Cause I'm getting an error "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: I don't understand your question. A ProcessBuilder requires a command list or array, one that is called as an external process on the operating system.